# TCP test tool for simultanously send/receive in a single connection

Tags: sockets, epoll

As we know TCP transmission of a single connection is full duplex. I'd like to test how my TCP proxy program behaves if I send/receive data on both client/server at the same time, like this:
client <----> tcp proxy <----> server

I used 'iperf' to complete single direction tests, but it cannot both send and receive in a same connection.

So anybody knows is there any test tool to satisfy my requirement?

BTW, here's the source code of my "TCP proxy" program, implemented with 'epoll':
 https://code.google.com/p/socksnat/source/browse/branches/rawtcp/src/rawtcp.c
It can be simply started like:
 ./rawtcp 0.0.0.0:5001 127.0.0.1:7001